# MVC 4 how to create dynamic controls

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dynamic-controls

I am using c# MVC 4 and I would like to create Multiple user controls and fill data dynamically.

Eg: I have a history filling form and in it i have to display multiple question having options control which can be radio button or check box also have a text-area with every question.So I do not know the field names and its control types prior to visiting this page, it gets the data and control types from a sql table with question:

field 1: Text-Label

field 2: DropdownList (values: 1,2,3,4,5) or radio button or check-box or text-box

field 3: textarea

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look in this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create "user controls" in MVC you should look into creating partials. It can serve as reusable components.

Comment: i Have used editor templates and all thing. but its creating for one control only i mean for one questions only.i want to do it for nearly 15 questions. @TGH